# Jekyll Site Not Showing Favicon

Tags: web, jekyll, favicon

My favicon is not displaying for my Jekyll site. I use the [minima](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) theme and followed all the instructions in the template for adding the favicon.

#### Expectation

[image: Expectation Image]

#### Reality

[image: Reality Image]

When I run the Jekyll site locally, the favicon displays. This is my header code included in the *header.html* file for a [similar project](https://github.com/Nazchanel/eshaniyer.tech) that is having the same issue

```html
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      {%- seo -%}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/main.css" | relative_url }}">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
      {%- feed_meta -%}
      {%- if jekyll.environment == 'production' and site.google_analytics -%}
        {%- include google-analytics.html -%}
      {%- endif -%}
    </head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi Nazchanel i think you have to add a absolute address on that

you are using

> `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">`

please try this may helps you

> `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{site.baseurl}}/assets/favicon.ico" />`

if this will not work then add

> `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="www.YourDomain.com/assets/favicon.ico" />`

Comment: In your 3rd option, wouldn't it be better to add an absolute URL using the Jekyll filter? "Prepend url and baseurl values to the input to convert a URL path to an absolute URL." See https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/

Comment: Yes exactly , we can use this also.

Comment: It also helps if my `_includes` folder was on my GitHub